# Plotly Subplot with multiple y-axis, plotting on the top plot, I need it to extra y-axis on the bottom plot

Tags: r-plotly

I am missing something in my code, which is making the 2nd y-axis to appear on the top plot instead of the bottom, I tried doing it in multiple ways.

```
# Code to make x & y labels bold
t2 <- list(size = 14, color = 'black', family = "Open Sans")

# Plot 1 using plotly subplots to plot 2 plots in one
fig <- plot_ly() %>% 
         add_trace(data=combined.Positive, x= ~Date, y = ~Survey,  type = 'bar', text= ~Survey, textposition = 'outside', name = 'Survey', 
                    bar= list(color = '#fff2e6'))%>%
         add_trace(data=combined.Positive, x= ~Date, y = ~Swab,  type = 'bar', text= ~Swab, textposition = 'outside', name = 'Swab', 
                   bar= list(color = 'rgb(224, 117, 11)')) %>% 
         layout(
           xaxis = list(fixedrange = T,
                             zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                             zerolinewidth = 2,
                             gridcolor = 'ffff',
                             showlegend = F),
                yaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero", side = "left"),
                font = t2 )
#Fig 2 will have 2 y-axis
figoverlay <- plot_ly() %>% 
               add_trace(data=cases, x= ~Date, y = ~cases.roll.7, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', fill = 'tozeroy', yaxis = "y1", 
                       fillcolor = 'rgba(255, 212, 96, 0.5)', opacity=0,
                       line = list(color = '#EEBD60', opacity=0),
                       marker = list(color = '#EEBD60', opacity=0), 
                       name = 'NC Cases') %>% 
               add_trace(data=cases, x= ~Date, y = ~(cases.roll.7/100000), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', fill = 'tozeroy', 
                        fillcolor = 'rgba(255, 212, 96, 0.5)', opacity=0,
                       line = list(color = '#EEBD60', opacity=0),
                       marker = list(color = '#EEBD60', opacity=0), yaxis="y2",
                       name = 'NC Cases %') %>%
               layout(plot_bgcolor='white', 
                      xaxis = list(fixedrange = T,
                                   zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                                   zerolinewidth = 2,
                                   gridcolor = 'ffff',
                                   showlegend = FALSE),
                       yaxis1 = list(side="left"),
                       yaxis2 = list(rangemode = "tozero", overlaying = "y1", side = "right"),
                      font = t2)

p <- subplot(fig, figoverlay, nrows = 2, shareX = FALSE) %>% 
      layout(legend=list(title=list(text='<b style="color:#00539B"> Positive Cases </b>')), font = t2)
```

p[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKJzZ.png)

Comment: Please format your question. You can use "Code" button to make it readable.

Comment: I did, thank you!